List<float[]> Problema al guardar arreglos
estoy realizando un programa que compruebe si un conjunto de números pseudo-aleatorios están distribuidos uniformemente. Para esto, estoy programando un método que realice la "prueba de serie".
Para esta prueba necesito crear pares de los números, de la siguiente manera:
{0.23, 0.54, 0.72, 0.19, 0.65} -> [0.23, 0.54] , [0.54, 0.72] , [0.72, 0.19] , [0.19, 0.65]
Mi problema viene al guardar estos pares en una lista de tipo List<float[]>, pues al imprimir los elementos de la lista se imprime el mismo par constantemente.
EL código es el siguiente:
Pseudorandom PseudoAleatorio = new Pseudorandom(1113, 47, 2212, 100);

List<float> LstNumerosPseudoAleatorios = PseudoAleatorio.Generator(10);

List<float[]> LstParesOrdenados = new List<float[]>();

float[] ParOrdenado = new float[2];

for (int i = 0; i < LstNumerosPseudoAleatorios.Count; i += 2)
{
ParOrdenado[0] = LstNumerosPseudoAleatorios[i];
ParOrdenado[1] = LstNumerosPseudoAleatorios[i + 1];
LstParesOrdenados.Add(ParOrdenado);
}

foreach (float[] Par in LstParesOrdenados)
{
Console.WriteLine($"[ {Par[0]} , {Par[1]} ]");
}

Console.ReadKey();

El resultado del ejemplo anterior debería ser:

[0.23 , 0.54]
[0.54 , 0.72]
[0.72 , 0.19]
[0.19 , 0.65]

Sin embargo, el resultado que obtengo es el siguiente:

[0.19 , 0.65]
[0.19 , 0.65]
[0.19 , 0.65]
[0.19 , 0.65]

Estuve usando el depurador y me di cuenta que cada vez que se ejecutaba la instrucción: LstParesOrdenados.Add(ParOrdenado);
los valores de cada arreglo se cambiaban a los del ultimo arreglo ingresado, por lo tanto, al final me quedaba una lista con el ultimo arreglo repetido.
¿Creen que podrían ayudarme? De antemano gracias.
Notas
Pseudorandom es una clase creada por mí para realizar los métodos necesarios para crear un número pseudo-aleatorio.
El método Pseudorandom.Generator() regresa una lista de valores del tamaño especificado en el parámetro.

Hola Javier, podrías decir si las respuestas dadas te resultaron útiles, y en caso de haberlo sido marcar como aceptada la que más te haya ayudado, gracias

Por cada iteración debes construir un nuevo arreglo ParOrdenado, actualmente construyes el arreglo fuera del ciclo for:
for (int i = 0; i < LstNumerosPseudoAleatorios.Count - 1; i++)
{
    float[] ParOrdenado = new float[2];

    ParOrdenado[0] = LstNumerosPseudoAleatorios[i];
    ParOrdenado[1] = LstNumerosPseudoAleatorios[i + 1];
    LstParesOrdenados.Add(ParOrdenado);
}

Los arreglos son tipos por referencia lo que significa que cualquier cambio que hagas en él se verá reflejado en cualquier variable que apunte hacia el arreglo, por eso todos los pares guardados en tu lista tienen los últimos valores guardados en tu arreglo.
Nota: Puedes buscar en internet más información sobre tipos por valor y tipos por referencia.

Además de lo que te indica @Javp, tienes otro error. Al recorrer el array, lo haces saltando 2 índices i += 2 esto te dará una excepción y además no cumple no la lógica que tu planteas, el recorrido debe ser hasta el largo - 1 y sumando 1
for (int i = 0; i < LstNumerosPseudoAleatorios.Count-1; i++)

Además, en lugar de utilizar un array ParOrdenado, puedes utilizar una tupla, ejemplo:
List<float> LstNumerosPseudoAleatorios = [ 0.23f, 0.54f, 0.72f, 0.19f, 0.65f ];
List<(float x, float y)> LstParesOrdenados = [];

for (int i = 0; i < LstNumerosPseudoAleatorios.Count-1; i++)
{
    LstParesOrdenados.Add((LstNumerosPseudoAleatorios[i], LstNumerosPseudoAleatorios[i + 1]));
}

foreach (var Par in LstParesOrdenados)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Par);
    //Console.WriteLine($"[ {Par.x} , {Par.y} ]");
}

Salida:
(0,23, 0,54)
(0,54, 0,72)
(0,72, 0,19)
(0,19, 0,65)

